# How to convert trailing minus sign

Tags: r

The data in the CSV file contains negative sign at the end.  How do I convert this as a regular number.

Data in CSV

```
Amount      
10
12.12-
41
42-
14.14-
```

Expected

```
10
-12.12
41
-42
-14.14
```

Comment: If `x` is your vector, you could do something like `as.numeric(sub("(.*)(-)", "\\2\\1", x))`

Comment: Thank you.  This worked very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(df1$Amount, "(?=-)", perl = TRUE), function(x) 
         as.numeric(paste(sort(x), collapse="")))
#[1]  10.00 -12.12  41.00 -42.00 -14.14
```

Comment: Thanks akrun.  Getting the following error                        RN<-sapply(strsplit(a$Amount, "(?=-)", perl = TRUE), function(x) 
+   as.numeric(paste(sort(x), collapse="")))
Error in strsplit(a$Arrear, "(?=-)", perl = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument.

Comment: @vesr  YOu have a `factor` class. just do `strsplit(as.character(df1$Amount), `

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.